# Abstract factory inside of model objects?

Tags: c++, model-view-controller

I have some Model classes and a controller (manager) class. Ideally, the controller needs to handle concrete model types without doing a down cast (this seems "correct"). I've thought of the Visitor Pattern and Abstract Factory patterns. Here is an example of my Model hierarchy:

```
class Animal {};
class Dog : public Animal {};
class Cat : public Animal {};
```

As my parser processes our data file (XML), certain element types map to different (but related) derived types. In my example, our XML defines different animals and we map the appropriate concrete type to each animal (since the data they hold varies and I wanted to avoid monolithic "Animal" classes that act as unions) through a factory method in my serialization class. However, these are stored as a list of `Animal` objects in the controller, so it can't know which are cats and which are dogs.

When the controller needs to process Cats differently from Dogs, I feel we can take a few approaches.

1. The controller does a down-cast of the type (dynamic_cast) or checks a virtual type member to determine if an object is a cat, and then process the cat. Same with dogs. I don't really like this solution.
2. Utilize Abstract Factory pattern so that each Model knows how to create a corresponding Controller object for each animal type. For example, `Model::Cat` has a member called `CreateControllerObject()` (polymorphic) and returns a `CatController` class. Note that the part that feels wrong about this solution is that the `Model::Cat` class will have a little bit of business logic, for example certain checks that will be done before we know we can create a cat. Typically Model objects are supposed to be "dumb data", so I'm not sure if it's OK to have "smart" models.
3. Use the visitor pattern directly on the Model classes, however this involves putting a great deal of controller logic in the models, which is why I suggested #2. At least in the #2 case the corresponding concrete animal controller class can be visited instead.

I'm not sure how else to implement it, so I wanted to get some design ideas from the SO community. None of the solutions I've come up with on my own feel right, although #2 feels the most correct and heads roughly in the right direction.

Comment: With the visitor pattern, controller logic will go in the concrete visitor, not in the model.

Comment: @Jarod42 My thoughts exactly. #3 in my list mentions this, but they key is that I'd need a corresponding controller hierarchy for my model hierarchy to store the controller logic itself and thus implement the visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double dispatch

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

```
class Controller
{
public:
   void update_animal(Dog &dog) { ... }
   void update_animal(Cat &cat) { ... }
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    virtual void update(Controller &controller)
    {
        controller.update_animal( *this );
    }
}
// same for Cat
```

Comment: If `Controller` derived from a `IAnimalVisitor`, it would be *double* dispatch. Actually, it is a *simple* dispatch.

Comment: @Jarod42 The wikipedia article makes it seem like double dispatch requires two vtable lookups. The solution here only involves 1 lookup but two function calls, so it's not double by that standard (but seems like an arbitrary rule?).

Comment: Also just to be clear, are you suggesting `update()` go inside the Model class? Is it OK to have my Model doing this? Or should I create another abstraction by creating corresponding controller objects (i.e. `DogController::update()`)?

Comment: Even if you create a DogController you would have to put it somewhere to the model class with this solution. Another solution is to add Dogs/Cats to a separate containers upon creation and then you don't have to do the dynamic type check during runtime.